# How to Create Dependent custom field under phone call activity in Netsuite CRM?

Tags: netsuite

I need to create dependent custom field of List/Record type, under phone call (CRM Fields). Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Help page titled "Multiple Dependent Dropdown Lists" that explains in detail how to set this up.

The short answer is to utilize the *Filtering* capabilities on the *Sourcing and Filtering* tab of your dependent custom field.

Comment: Thanks @erictgrubaugh. Yes I found that Help page titled "Multiple Dependent Dropdown Lists". In that page they mentioned need to create custom record type in order to create dependent custom field, but in CRM i didn't found the menu to create new record type. I seen that "Record type" menu shown under "Lists->Relationship" in some reference pages. I think record type is not enabled in my account. Could you please guide me how to enable it on my account? Thanks in advance.